# Is it possible to seed the release revision for a release plan?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

We're migrating over from another build tool where relied on the CI to maintain a release version that increments based on a given pattern. In VSTS, the release revision id autoincrements from 1, but we deploy to targets that require a newer version number than the current one.

I'd really rather not create hundreds of fake releases to push the version number up or have to manage the version number myself.

Is there a way to seed the release version with a starting number? Or, alternatively, is it possible for a release to modify a release plan's variable (so that the changed value is available to future releases)?

Comment: What' the release plan? Are you meaning release definition in vNext?

Comment: Release Definitions are on vCurrent of VSTS, maybe that's vNext of TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom variables, that enable you to do this.

To view, edit, and add new **[release definition variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/more-release-definition#release-definition-variables)**, open the **Variables** tab of a release definition.

[image]

Comment: Ah good point. I can offset the release number by a variable amount.